# Scrapy- HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed despite user-agent changed

Tags: python, scrapy, http-headers

I'm having a hard time trying to scrape a website rendering all its page in JS : https://www.jobteaser.com/en/job-offers

After checking the requests with the debugger tool I saw that all the content I want is sent with AJAX in .`json` format.

[The file returning the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ttww.png)

So I've done the following spider to get the content of a specific search :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
import json

class JobteaserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="jobteaser"
    start_urls=['https://www.jobteaser.com/fr/job-offers?q%3Dbusiness%20analyst%26contract%3Dstage%2Cinternship%2Cwerkstudent%26location%3DFrance..France%26locale%3Dfr%2Cen']

    def parse(self,response):

        apiKey="..."

        header ={
            "requests":[
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=*&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=abroad_only&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=company_business_type&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=company_sectors&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=contract_duration&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=contract&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=locale&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=location&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=position_category&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},
                {"indexName":"job_offers",
                "params":"query=business%20analyst&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22contract%3Astage%22%2C%22contract%3Ainternship%22%2C%22contract%3Awerkstudent%22%5D%2C%5B%22location%3AFrance%22%5D%2C%5B%22locale%3Afr%22%2C%22locale%3Aen%22%5D%5D&hitsPerPage=20&page=0&facets=start_date&distinct=true&facetingAfterDistinct=true"},

            ],
            "apiKey":apiKey

        }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://9vcp793ivh-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.30.0&x-algolia-application-id=9VCP793IVH",
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps(header),
            headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            callback=self.parse_internship)


    def parse_internship(self,response):
        yield{"E":response.body}
        pass
```

The headers are also sent in a `.json` format. `USER_AGENT` has been changed and the `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` set to `False`. Despite these actions I'm having this error :

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.jobteaser.com/fr/job-offers?q%3Dbusiness%20analyst%26contract%3Dstage%2Cinternship%2Cwerkstudent%26location%3DFrance..France%26locale%3Dfr%2Cen> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://9vcp793ivh-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.30.0&x-algolia-application-id=9VCP793IVH> (referer: https://www.jobteaser.com/)
INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://9vcp793ivh-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.30.0&x-algolia-application-id=9VCP793IVH>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

It might be the URL sent through the Request that is not good but I can't find the right one after a thorough analysis of the original URL.

Thanks !

Comment: you're likely missing some items in the header. and for what it's worth, I'm not convinced scrapy actually makes anything easier.

Comment: I've copy paste the exact same header from normal live test (using my browser). Maybe the apiKey has to be changed, I will try that. Why Scrapy is not making the  thing easier ?

Comment: Idk it just doesn't seem easier than just using requests and beautifulsoup, but just preference.

Comment: But 400 is the "access denied" code. The server is probably doing checks on headers or cookies to make sure that post request is coming from the JS/AJAX

Comment: Is it possible to fake/simulate that ? Also can a file in fact be checking more headers like ones from other pages (for instance checking headers on a referer page...). I don't have a big picture of the scope of the information that can be asked by a request/page ahah

Comment: Yea it can be faked, not always easy though. Double check your url too, when i go to that link, i only see 1 post request, and it's to this url `https://9vcp793ivh-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries`

Comment: Just because I'm curious, do you have any resources to learn how to do such things ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was a lot easier than I thought, apiKey just had to be retrieve from another page displaying `json` data. Then when the right apiKey is set the page is sending the wanted content.